# Content not loading on horizontal scroll view

Tags: ios

Hi I am building an app in which I want my contents to be displayed on a view which is horizontally scroll-able.
I have implemented the following code for it:

```
-(void)DownLoadData:(NSString *)indexSelect
{




    self._parserForNewsDetail = [afaqsParser getInstance];
    [[afaqsParser getInstance] setCacheNeed:TRUE];
    [self._parserForNewsDetail   parseWithUrl:[_arrUrlLinks objectAtIndex:[indexSelect integerValue]] UrlTypefor:nil];
    NSDictionary *resultDic;
       resultDic = [[[self._parserForNewsDetail getLinkAndIdDic] valueForKey:@"items"]objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"Detail Dic = %@",[resultDic description]);
    if (resultDic== NULL || resultDic ==nil)
    {
        //Check internet here
        [[SharedUtilities getInstance]RemoveActivityIndicatorView];
        [SharedUtilities ShowAlert:@"No Data Found" title:nil withView:self.view];
        return;
    }

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(SetValuesInUserInterface:)  withObject: resultDic waitUntilDone:NO];


        [[SharedUtilities getInstance]RemoveActivityIndicatorView];
}


-(void)DownloadNext:(NSString *)indexSelect
{
    resultDic = [[[self._parserForNewsDetail getLinkAndIdDic] valueForKey:@"items"]objectAtIndex:0];
    NSURL *imgurl =[NSURL URLWithString:[[Dic valueForKey:@"image"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    NSArray *subviewsArr = [self.view subviews];
    for (int i=0; i<[subviewsArr count]; i++) {
        if ([[subviewsArr objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[ImageDownLoader class]]) {



        }
    }
 [self loadScrollView];

}





-(void)SetValuesInUserInterface:(NSDictionary *)Dic
{


    self._imageView1.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
    self._imageView1.clipsToBounds = YES;


    self._imageView1.tag = 999;
       NSURL *imgurl =[NSURL URLWithString:[[Dic valueForKey:@"image"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    self._imageView1.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgurl]];


    NSArray *subviewsArr = [self.view subviews];
    for (int i=0; i<[subviewsArr count]; i++) {
        if ([[subviewsArr objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[ImageDownLoader class]]) {
            [[subviewsArr objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];


        }
    }

     if ([[Dic valueForKey:@"image"] isEqual:@""])
    {

        _imageView1.hidden=YES;

        _txtView.frame=CGRectMake(4.0f,95.0f,_txtView.frame.size.width,_txtView.frame.size.height );


        NSLog(@"NO IMAGE");
    }
    else{
        _imageView1.hidden=NO;
        _imageView1.frame=CGRectMake(4.0f,95.0f,310.0f,180.0f );
        // _txtView.frame=CGRectMake(4.0f,316.0f,310.0f,159.0f );
        _txtView.frame=CGRectMake(4.0f,316.0f,_txtView.frame.size.width,_txtView.frame.size.height );

        NSLog(@"IMAGE VISIBLE");
    }



    self._scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;

    self._scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
    self._scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
    self._header.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-MediumCond" size:18];
    [self._header setText: [Dic valueForKey:@"header"]];
    self._header.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    [self._Writer  setText:[Dic valueForKey:@"AUTHOR"]];
    [self._kicker setText:[Dic valueForKey:@"kicker"]];
    [self._txtView setText:[Dic valueForKey:@"ARTICLE_BODY"]];

    NSString *writer;
    if ([[Dic valueForKey:@"AUTHOR"] length]>2)
    {
        writer=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,  ",[Dic valueForKey:@"AUTHOR"]];
    }
    else
    {
        writer=@"";
    }




    [self._Writer setText:str];
    [_txtView sizeToFit]; //added
    [_txtView layoutIfNeeded]; //added

    CGRect frame = self._txtView.frame;
    self._txtView.frame = frame;
    [_txtView setScrollEnabled:NO];
    self._scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,440+frame.size.height);

    _titleLabel.frame= CGRectMake(0, self._scrollView.contentSize.height-119, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 40);
    _titleLabel.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1];
    _titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    _titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13.5];
    _titleLabel.numberOfLines=2;

    [self._scrollView addSubview:_titleLabel];

     [self loadScrollView];

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}






- (void)viewDidLoad
{


      [self DownLoadData:resultDic];


    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(loadScrollView)];
    rightRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [rightRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];

    //add the your gestureRecognizer , where to detect the touch..
    [_scrollView addGestureRecognizer:rightRecognizer];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(loadScrollView)];
    leftRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [leftRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];



    [_scrollView addGestureRecognizer:leftRecognizer];


}

- (void)rightSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{




    [self btnPreviousClick];
    [self loadScrollView];



}


- (void)leftSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"leftSwipeHandle");
    [self btnNextClick];
    [self loadScrollView];


}

-(IBAction)btnNextClick
{
    btnPreviousNews.userInteractionEnabled=TRUE;
    if(count!=[_arrUrlLinks count] -1)
    {
        if(count==[_arrUrlLinks count]-2)
        {
            btnNextNews.userInteractionEnabled=FALSE;
            [btnNextNews setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow2_next.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        [btnPreviousNews setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow1_prev.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        count=count +1;
        _lblNewsCount.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d",count+1,[_arrUrlLinks count]];
        NSLog(@"next %d",count);
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(DownLoadData:) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count]];


    }
    else{
        btnNextNews.userInteractionEnabled=FALSE;
    }
}
-(void)btnPreviousClick

{

    btnNextNews.userInteractionEnabled=TRUE;
    if(count==0)
    {
        btnPreviousNews.userInteractionEnabled=FALSE;
    }
    else{
        if(count==1)
        {
            [btnPreviousNews setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow2_prev.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            btnPreviousNews.userInteractionEnabled=FALSE;
        }
        [btnNextNews setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow1_next.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        count=count-1;

        _lblNewsCount.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d",count+1,[_arrUrlLinks count]];
        NSLog(@"previous %d",count);
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(DownLoadData:) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count]];
    }
}

-(void)loadScrollView

{

    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, _scrollView.frame.size.height);


    NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < [_arrUrlLinks count]; i++) {

        [controllers addObject:[NSNull null]];

    }

    self.viewControllers = controllers;
    count=1;


    // a page is the width of the scroll view

    _scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width * [_arrUrlLinks count], _scrollView.frame.size.height);

    _scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator =YES;

    _scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;

    _scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;

    _scrollView.delegate = self;


    pageControl.numberOfPages = [_arrUrlLinks count];

    pageControl.currentPage = 0;


    [_scrollView addSubview:_txtView];
    [_txtView setText:[Dic valueForKey:@"ARTICLE_BODY"]];
    [controller.view addSubview:_txtView];


    // pages are created on demand

    // load the visible page

    // load the page on either side to avoid flashes when the user starts scrolling

    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:0];

    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:1];

}





- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page {

    if (page < 0) return;

    if (page >= [_arrUrlLinks count])

        return;


    // replace the placeholder if necessary

    controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];

    if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null]) {

        NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;

        if([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])

        {

            controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];

        }

        else{

            controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController_ipad" bundle:nil];

        }

        [controller initWithPageNumber:page];


        //  [controller.view addSubview:_txtView];
        //  [controller.view addSubview:_imageview];
        NSLog(@"loadscrollviewwithpage");

        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];

        // [controller release];

    }


    // add the controller's view to the scroll view

    if (nil == controller.view.superview) {

        CGRect frame = _scrollView.frame;

        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;

        frame.origin.y = 0;

        controller.view.frame = frame;
        // _txtView.frame=frame;
        // _imageview.frame=frame;
        // _txtView.frame=CGRectMake(4.0f,316.0f,310.0f,159.0f );
        _txtView=@"hello";
        // [controller.view addSubview:_txtView];
        [_imageView1 addSubview:controller.view];
       // [_txtView addSubview:controller.view];
        //  [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
        NSLog(@"loadscrollviewwithpage................>>>>>>>>>>>>");
      //  [self._header setText: [Dic valueForKey:@"header"]];
            // [self DownLoadData:resultDic];
        //[self SetValuesInUserInterface:Dic];
        [self DownloadNext:resultDic];


    }

}

- (void)unloadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page {

    if (page < 0) return;

    if (page >= [_arrUrlLinks count]) return;



    controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];



    if ((NSNull *)controller != [NSNull null]) {

        if (nil != controller.view.superview)

            [controller.view removeFromSuperview];



        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:[NSNull null]];

        //  [controller.view addSubview:_txtView];
        //  [controller.view addSubview:_imageview];
        NSLog(@"Unloadscrollviewwithpage");



        //        [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

    }

}



- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {

    // We don't want a "feedback loop" between the UIPageControl and the scroll delegate in

    // which a scroll event generated from the user hitting the page control triggers updates from

    // the delegate method. We use a boolean to disable the delegate logic when the page control is used.

    if (pageControlUsed) {

        // do nothing - the scroll was initiated from the page control, not the user dragging

        return;

    }


    // Switch the indicator when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible

    CGFloat pageWidth = _scrollView.frame.size.width;

    int page = floor((_scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;

    pageControl.currentPage = page;

    //    NSLog(@"current page %d",page);


    // load the visible page and the page on either side of it (to avoid flashes when the user starts scrolling)

    [self unloadScrollViewWithPage:page - 2];

    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:page - 1];

    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:page];

    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:page + 1];

    [self unloadScrollViewWithPage:page + 2];

    count=page+1;


    //  [self newCountTitleSet];

    // A possible optimization would be to unload the views+controllers which are no longer visible

}



// At the begin of scroll dragging, reset the boolean used when scrolls originate from the UIPageControl

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollViewLoc

{

    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollViewLoc.frame.size.width;

    CGPoint translation = [scrollViewLoc.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:scrollViewLoc.superview];

    int page = floor((scrollViewLoc.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;



    if(translation.x > 0)

    {

        if(_strCurrentNewsSelect!=0)

        {

            if(page==0)

            {
                NSLog(@"OK");

                NSLog(@"scrollviewwillbegindragging=0");




               [self DownLoadDataPrevious:[_strCurrentNewsSelect.integervalue]-1];

            }

        }

        else{

            if(page==1)

            {
                NSLog(@"previous button");
                 [self btnPreviousClick];


            }

        }



    } else

    {

        //   [_txtView  setText:[Dic valueForKey:@"ARTICLE_BODY"]];
        //  [controller.view addSubview:_txtView];

        //  [controller.view addSubview:_txtView];
        //  [controller.view addSubview:_imageview];
        NSLog(@"loadscrollviewwithpage else");

        [self btnPreviousClick];



        NSLog(@"previous news");

        //        if(galleryItemClick+1!=[arrGallaeryUrl count])
        //
        //        {
        //
                   if(page+1==[_arrUrlLinks count])
        //
                    {
        //
                        NSLog(@"====....>>>>>>>");


                    }

        count=count+1;





    }

}
```

By using this code I am able to create the view controllers according to my array count[_arrUrlLinks] but the contents are not loaded on these views. On my first view I can only see an image view in black color rest of the views are blank.
How can I get the contents loaded on these views?

Comment: You are adding `controller.view` to `_imageView1` not to `_scrollView `. And make `controller` a local variable in `loadScrollViewWithPage:`

Comment: no this is not working